# Is the science community reluctant to consider the evidence to support some sort of higher intelligence?

Tags: multiverse, creator

Scientists can explain how life has developed to the stage we are at today, but they can’t explain why the process of evolution exists or what the spark was that brought life about at all. We are still clueless as to what ignited the Big Bang if that was in fact the beginning of our universe.

Science also argues that a multiverse theory counteracts the ‘fine tuning’ argument for a creator.

The logical answer to our existence and the existence of our universe is surely that there is a higher intelligence at work.

Scientists argue, who created the creator then? Well, just like an insect cannot get close to comprehending the workings of a wrist watch, then we  probably can’t get close to comprehending what is beyond the higher intelligence that may be at work - It is beyond our realm of thinking. As humans we need to know the cause of any effect, however beyond us there may be no need to ask why or how, there may be a different form of contemplation.

It seems as though the science community in general are very reluctant to contemplate the creator theory, but I can’t help but feel it is the most logical conclusion.

No specific question here but I’d love to hear your thoughts on:

- Perceived reluctance in the Science community to consider the creator theory.
- thoughts on ‘fine tuning’ as evidence of a creator.
- thoughts on whether there’s a limit to what we can conceivably understand and so we shouldn’t bat off the the counter argument to a creator with the argument ‘who created the creator?’

Comment: If a higher intelligence is beyond human comprehension, how is citing it as an explanation different from not knowing?

Answer (score 3):

I wonder what's happened to the concept of faith...

Look, science is ultimately functional. It wants theories it can 'do stuff' with; it wants understandings that give it insight into the pragmatic workings of the world. Faith concepts may be a lot of things, but they are not pragmatic and functional in that mundane, materialistic, pedantic sense. Many scientists are people of faith, but their faith doesn't intrude on their work as scientists because there's nothing functional they can do with it.

It's like giving a chef a live chicken: what's she going to do with *that*? Live chickens have no place in the kitchen.

The intelligent design, fine-tuned universe thing is perfectly fine as far as it goes (if that's what one wants to believe), but from a scientific perspective it has all the impact of putting a happy-face sticker on an electronic device. The sticker doesn't help explain how the device runs, and it isn't an integral component. One could argue that the sticker is all that holds the device together, I suppose — I have a remote control like that — but what does that have to do with the thing itself? At best, slapping a happy-face on the device makes us feel better about it, all warm and fuzzy; at worst, it peels off and gums up the insides so the device doesn't work the way it's supposed to.

There may or may not be a god(s) who created and run the universe; that I don't know. But *theorizing* about some god having created the universe is merely sticking a big, fat happy-face sticker over that great empty space in our metaphysical worldviews. It has no place in the scientific world, and (if I may be frank) it has no place in the religious world either. We should face that abyss with courage and grace so we can come to terms with it, not hide it or ignore it. That is what it means to have faith, and (again, frankly) it's also what it means to be scientific.

We shouldn't try to be *logical* at the expense of being *reasonable*. That road only leads us to places we don't want to go.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the physics community rejects creationism is that there's no physical evidence to support that hypothesis, despite humans having searched for it for hundreds if not thousands of years. And many things long attributed to divine intervention, like cerebrovascular accidents (once called "strokes of god"), turned out to have nonmagical causes.

Were the universe we inhabit not fine-tuned to allow life as we know it to evolve, we wouldn't be here to make that observation.

Finally, it is not the program of physics or science in general to give up and rather than dig deeper for more subtle causes attribute everything else to a creator. That constitutes religion, and as such is unequivocally outside the arena of science.

Answer (score 0):

Scientists are not reluctant, because for the scientific community to be reluctant to consider evidence for creationism/intelligent design, first there need to be evidence. So far, there is none to consider.

What poses as evidence is only a "God of the gaps" argument, i.e. "we don't know therefore the most logical explanation is God" (I assume a hypothetical higher intelligence responsible for creating and fine tuning the universe could be called a god, I see no problem with this). This approach has several flaws and can't be rigorously considered to be evidence.

1. "The most logical explanation" lacking any other, whatever that is, does not mean "the good explanation". At best it is a best guess, a hint of what an explanation could be and a direction for future research, to be dismissed as soon as an empirically supported explanation is found. Historically, the god of the gap argument has only been losing ground as one unexplained phenomenon after the other found a mundane explanation. It is indeed a sorry hill to die on.
2. Even if a scientist as a person could be convinced by the argument (anyone is entitled to their opinion after all), as a scientist there is nothing to be considered. What experience, what verification protocol do you suggest to empirically demonstrate, that is to say actually provide evidence for, the validity of the higher intelligence hypothesis?
3. The goal of scientists is not merely to provide explanations, but to provide models allowing predictions about the future. Simply claiming a supernatural intelligence as the cause of the universe can explain anything but has no predictive power, nobody can use it to predict the result of an experiment (in fact, if it could be used to make predictions, those predictions would provide a valid experiment for my point 2).
4. If we are unable to comprehend the hypothetical creator in the same way a fruit fly can't comprehend a watch, then why bother with scientific inquiry in the first place ? Science is the methodical application of reason in order to understand phenomenons. Therefore it has no purpose in trying to tackle problems our reason can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

> Perceived reluctance in the Science community to consider the creator theory.

Many scientists believe in a creator, but belief in a creator is completely irrelevant to scientific inquiry. If you want to argue otherwise, you will have to present the empirical evidence that a belief in a creator can be the foundation for a scientific theory about the real world.

> thoughts on ‘fine tuning’ as evidence of a creator.

No. We won't ever be able to explain reality as a whole. This is most plausibly because we are the natural product of natural selection. So, our intelligence works in a certain way. Essentially, we are logical beings. This means that an explanation is essentially an assumption from which we can logically derive what we want to explain. Crucially, we also dismiss as circular any explanation which starts from what it is we want to explain. The reasoning "X implies X" is no explanation for why X is true.

However, this means that if we were to explain reality as a whole, we would have to explain it in terms of something else than reality, and something else than reality  by definition doesn't exist.

So, anything we could explain reality with doesn't exist. Thus, we cannot explain reality, not logically at any rate, not according to human logic. This means that any explanation of reality is inevitably nonsensical. Still, you do that if you like it.

Once you understand that we will not ever be able to understand reality as a whole, you come back to Earth and you start to think in pragmatic terms. What can we understand, and how can we use our intelligence to improve our lives? This is essentially why we do science. If you don't believe me, look at how costly it is to do science these days. We wouldn't do it if it was just to assuage our metaphysical angst.

The multiverse of course falsifies the idea of fine tuning. However, this is more profound than that. We won't ever be able to understand why our universe is what it is. All we might succeed doing, is find something X that will explain our universe, but then, we would immediately be faced with the new problem of explaining X.

In effect, this is the main problem of religious people who want to explain our world through a divine creator. Logically, this means that they have now to explain the divine creator. They usually pretend to solve this problem by claiming that a creator does not need  to have been created, and this without realising that this falsifies their claim that everything that exists has to be created by something else. Bad logic.

> thoughts on whether there’s a limit to what we can conceivably understand and so we shouldn’t bat off the the counter argument to a creator with the argument ‘who created the creator?’

Well, this is typical. You want to say that we can understand the need for a creator and that we cannot understand that there should be a creator to begin with.

No, the problem here is that you don't know that there needs to be any creator at all. Reality exists, we don't know why and we won't ever know why. Is that enough for you as a limit to our understanding?

Of course, this is compatible with a divine creator, i.e., a divine creator *might* be the explanation for the existence of our universe. However, there is nothing logical in that. There is nothing necessary in the existence of a divine creator. There is nothing necessary in the existence of an intelligent creator. Maybe one day we might understand why our universe exists, but it will be in terms of something else and something that we won't understand why it exists. Thus, the ultimate explanation doesn't exist and pretending otherwise is fallacious. Still, you do it if you like to do that sort of thing.